# What is the expected JSON Block for a desire2learn POST Org Parent?

Tags: desire2learn, valence

I believe I have tried all combinations to POST to this route and continue to get a 404.  What am I doing wrong?

I want to set the parent of a courseOffering to a different, but existing courseTemplate.  The courseOffering orgUnitId is 31273, the new parent (courseTemplate) orgUnitId is 31286.  The route is use is:
POST .../d2l/api/lp/1.2/orgstructure/31273/parents/
(also tried without the trailing /)
The JSON Block is:
{"OrgUnitId":31286}

I have also tried Id and Identifier instead of OrgUnitId and a string, "31286" instead of an int and orgUnitId (lower case) - all result in 404.

fwiw, a get with the same route works just fine.

cwt
from the Valence docs:
POST /d2l/api/lp/(version)/orgstructure/(orgUnitId)/parents/
Give the provided org unit a new parent org unit.

Parameters: 
version (D2LVERSION) – API version.
orgUnitId (D2LID) – Org unit ID.
JSON Parameters:

OrgUnitId (D2LID as single JSON number) – Org unit to add as a parent.

Answer (score 0):

The docs say that the expected input data for this POST is an org unit ID value provided as "a single JSON number".

When you say you're passing:

```
{"OrgUnitId": 31286}
```

what you're providing is a JSON object (composite) with a single property, named "OrgUnitId" that has a JSON number value. In fact, what you should provide is:

```
31286
```

But you should still indicate this is a JSON body, so you should set the HTTP request `Content-Type` header to `application/json`). Here's an excerpt from an interactive session successfully making this call; we dump the various components of the HTTP response/request object for you (r is the response, r.request is the original request that prompted the response):

```
In [40]: r.request.method
Out[40]: 'POST'

In [41]: r.request.url
Out[41]: 'https://{host}/d2l/api/lp/1.1/orgstructure/8083/parents/?x_b={user_id}&x_c={app_sig}&x_a={app_id}&x_d={user_sig}&x_t=1391183251'

In [42]: r.request.headers
Out[42]: CaseInsensitiveDict({'Content-Length': '4', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.2.1 CPython/3.3.3 Darwin/12.5.0', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, compress'})

In [43]: r.request.body
Out[43]: '6984'

In [44]: r.status_code
Out[44]: 200
```

Course offerings and course templates have a special relationship in that every course offering must have a course template as a parent. You might be able to first add the new course template as a parent to the course offering, and then delete the old one, or the back-end service might just not let you sever off a course template from a course offering at all.